# No tag "tableFacade" defined in tag library imported with prefix "jmesa"

Tags: jsp-tags, taglib, jmesa

Im new to jmesa and doing some debugging for a new aplication.

I get this error @:

```
  <jmesa:tableFacade
            id="tag" 
            stateAttr="restore"
            items="${beans}"
            maxRows="15"
            maxRowsIncrements="10,15,25,50"
            var="bean"
            toolbar="${custom_toolbar}"
            view="${custom_view}">
```

I checked the jmesa.tld file that I unzipped from the download site...and theres no mention of a "tablefacade" tag anywhere?

whats the issue here?  I would think there needs to be a declaration of that tag name in the .tld file according to the error??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tableFacade tag was renamed to tableModel ([see here](http://code.google.com/p/jmesa/wiki/JMesa3Examples)).